# How can I block certain words from being used in Django forms?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

So I am creating a website where users can make posts, but I want to block certain words from being used in the Django form. For example, I don't want them to mention CP, or anything else illegal. How could I block these words from being displayed or throw an error message at the user

I haven't really tried anything, but I have been researching, to no luck.

Here is the post model.

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=250)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True,auto_now_add=True)
    tags = TaggableManager()

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def approve_comments(self):
        return self.comments.filter(approved_comment=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('mainapp:post_detail',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

And here is the form

```py
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Post
        fields = ('title','text')
        widgets = {
            'title':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'textinputclass'}),
            'text':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'textareaclass'}),
        }
```

And here is the CreatePostView

```py
class CreatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'mainapp/post_details.html'
    form_class = PostForm
    model = Post
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

I want it so that it throws an error if you include a word that's blocked
Thank you for any help that you can give :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if understand you correctly, but maybe you searching for https://github.com/ReconCubed/django-profanity-filter

EDIT.
You can add your own "wrong" words to the list in wordlist.txt file

Comment: I am using https://github.com/ReconCubed/django-profanity-filter but I never knew how to add words to the word list how do you do that?

Comment: @A_K You can use https://github.com/ReconCubed/django-profanity-filter/blob/5f7f20a841acf3c0f1142aecfd8af12477b3012e/extras.py#L33

Comment: @Nju How do i use  this in models.py and views.py ?